# Caching headers CakePHP

Tags: jquery-mobile, http-headers, cakephp-1.3

Goodmorning lads,

First of all - R.I.P TPB! Welcome malaysiabay.org for the Dutchies <3

Ok, on topic! Since 2 weeks I'm inside the Cake framework and working on a mobile webapp with jQuery for Android users. Because it's an mobile app I'm trying to get the loading time as low as possible. Google helps me a lot with their speedtest but they're telling me to add php headers with an expire date... I understand what I've got too do, but whatever I try.. the CakePHP framework is always overruling my custom made headers. Can you tell me how cake handles the http-headers.. or tell me what too improve on the webpage?

Example: http://www.naviplan.nl/pages/routeportal/2/2/

https://developers.google.com/pagespeed/#url=http_3A_2F_2Fwww.naviplan.nl_2Fpages_2Frouteportal_2F2_2F0_2F&mobile=false&rule=LeverageBrowserCaching

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.
After installing Chrome's plugin `Page Speed` it checked all the wrong html / css and gave me a good solution for it. Decreasing it's imagesize, css-size and the overall page loading.

I also got CakePHP running flawlessly again, changed some row in my core.php which fixed the caching problem.